# Why Segeo UI font family is not working on Mac while on windows it is working fine

Tags: css, reactjs, font-face, font-family

[image]

Segeo UI is builtin font family in browser.I have font family files that I am using in my react project. But the problem is that it works perfectly on Windows. however the font family didn't apply when I opened it on a Mac. Could you kindly tell me what the problem is and how to resolve it?

Why i'm applying important it so that i didn't apply builtin font family
App.scss:

```
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI" !important;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Segoe UI" !important;
  // src: url("./assets/fonts/SegoeUI.eot");
  src: url("./assets/fonts/SegoeUI.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("./assets/fonts/SegoeUI.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("./assets/fonts/SegoeUI.woff") format("woff"),
    url("./assets/fonts/SEGOEUI.TTF") format("TTF");
  // url("./assets/fonts/SegoeUI.svg#SegoeUI") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-display: swap !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what is meant by : "Segeo UI is builtin font family in browser" and are you certain that on MAC it is either 'builtin' or properly loaded by your font-family settings (ie is it in the right folder?).

Comment: @AHaworth like Sans Serif i can use the Segoe UI without any files because browser provide this font family.

Comment: I’m confused, if it’s built in why are you trying to load it?

Comment: Actually the built in and custom file font styles is a little bit different the issue is why it is not loading on mac

Comment: So it is not built in and you want to load it. Have you checked the link is correct?

Comment: What is your folder structure? Were do you load your font files from?

Comment: @Apodemus See i update the question. SS of folder structure is attached

Comment: Okay, looks fine to me. If you build your project does it package the fonts along with it?

Comment: @Apodemus In static folder i have css js media only